# Java URLEncoder keep case of original message but make UTF-8 code lowercase

Tags: java, utf-8, url-encoding, case-sensitive

**I am using URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8"); to encode a string.**

**The problem is that I need the UTF-8 codes in the final string to be lower case, while maintaining the case of the original message.**

Example:

Message: {Message

Desired Output: %5bMessage

URLEncoder.encode("{Message", "UTF-8"); -> %5BMessage

URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8").toLowerCase(); -> %5bmessage

**Is there a way to change the behavior of URLEncoder?**

or

**Is there an easy way to convert all the UTF-8 codes to lower case after the fact, for all UTF-8 characters and for arbitrary string length?**

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I need the UTF-8 codes in the final string to be lower case, while maintaining the case of the original message.

I take it you mean that you want the hexadecimal digits in the URL escapes to be expressed in lowercase (these are not "UTF-8 codes").  Anyway, this is a crummy problem to have, because the specifications for URL Encoding (a.k.a. "percent encoding") explicitly specify that the hex digits in percent codes are case insensitive.  Two percent-encoded URLs that differ only in the case of those hex digits are equivalent, so code that treats them otherwise is likely to be a continual problem as long as it is in use.

> Is there a way to change the behavior of URLEncoder?

[The docs of `java.net.URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) are pretty brief.  It doesn't take much of an examination to see that no, there is no mechanism for modulating this aspect of its behavior.  You could write your own implementation (it's not that hard), or you might find a third-party encoder, but the standard library's encoder will not satisfy your requirement.

> Is there an easy way to convert all the UTF-8 codes to lower case after the fact, for all UTF-8 characters and for arbitrary string length?

It depends on what you mean by "easy".  It is possible in principle to perform such a conversion, but by the time you're parsing and updating the encoded URL, you've spent at least twice as much effort as it would have taken to perform the encoding the way you wanted in the first place.

But if you really want to do that, then you might use something like this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class URLRecoder {
    private final static Pattern CODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("%[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}");

    /**
     * Recodes a URL-encoded string to ensure that all hex digits in the
     * percent codes that are not decimal digits are expressed in lowercase.
     */
    public String recode(String urlString) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher m = CODE_PATTERN.matcher(urlString);

        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group().toLowerCase());
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's hardcoded into URLEncoder (I'm looking at Oracle's JDK btw). The conversion basically converts your character, and gets the hexadecimal value for each character, and then subtracts the difference between `'a' -'A'` (uppercase to lowercase difference in char value), to force an uppercase value.

```
if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
    ch -= caseDiff;
}
```

The only way I would think you could get around this is to use reflection and modify `URLEncoder#caseDiff` to be 0, seeing as this variable is static final:

```
static final int caseDiff = ('a' - 'A');
```

by doing something like (consider this psudeo-code. You'll want to take a second pass at it):

```
try {
    Field declaredField = URLEncoder.class.getDeclaredField("caseDiff");
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");

    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(declaredField, declaredField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    declaredField.setAccessible(true);
    declaredField.setInt(null, 0);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm actually genuinely curious at your intention for doing this though, and I'm wondering if this is really what you want to do.

Comment: I wholesale copied the URLEncoder source into a new class and changed caseDiff = 0. It didn't do anything. caseDiff isn't actually used anywhere in URLEncoder.

Comment: That's not true. I can tell you right now that in Java 1.8.80, it is used on line 276 and 281.

Comment: I performed exactly what you claim to have tried and I get lowercase hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to copy the URLEncoder source into a new class and change the hexStr constant from "0123456789ABCDEF" to "0123456789abcdef".

Not going to post the code here because of possible licensing issues:

```
/*===========================================================================
* Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
 * "Restricted Materials of IBM"
 * 
 * IBM SDK, Java(tm) Technology Edition, v8
 * (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1995, 2013. All Rights Reserved
 *
 * US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure
 * restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
 *===========================================================================
 */
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.`
```

Source Version:

```
 * @version 1.31, 11/17/05
```